# Shell script for generating HTML out put

Tags: shell

The following script is generating the desired out put but  not redirecting the result to   /home/myuser/slavedelay.html

#!/bin/bash

```
host=<ip>
echo $host
user=usr1
password=mypass
threshold=300
statusok=OK
statuscritical=CRITICAL

for i in ert7 ert9
do
echo "<html>" > /home/myuser/slavedelay.html

if [ "$i" == "ert7" ]; then
        slvdelay=`mysql  -u$user -p$password -h<ip> -S /backup/mysql/mysql.sock -e 'show slave status\G' | grep Seconds_Behind_Master | sed -e 's/ *Seconds_Behind_Master: //'`
         if [ $slvdelay -ge $threshold ]; then
                echo "<tr><td>$i</td><td>CRITICAL</td>"  >> /home/myuser/slavedelay.html
                echo "<tr><td>$i</td><td>CRITICAL</td>" 
        else
                echo "<tr><td>$i</td><td>OK</td>"  >> /home/myuser/slavedelay.html
                echo "<tr><td>$i</td><td>OK</td>"
         fi
fi
done
echo "</html>" >> /home/myuser/slavedelay.html
```

If I cat the output file  /home/myuser/slavedelay.html it gives.

```
<html>
</html>
```

Execution result :

```
sh slave_delay.sh 
<tr><td>sdb7</td><td>OK</td>
```

Comment: Put the outout file name in a variable so you're sure you don't have a typo in it (I'm guessing you edited it before posting and that could be the issue).

Comment: Tried still the same issue.. documentroot=/home/myuser/slavedelay.html, everywhere the documentroot has replaced with file path

Answer (score 2):

Each time through the loop you're emptying the output file because of the command

```
echo "<html>" > /home/myuser/slavedelay.html
```

So the first iteration writes the `<tr>` row to the file, then the next iteration overwrites the file and doesn't write those lines because `$i` isn't `ert7`.

Change it to:

```
for i in ert7 ert9
do
if [ "$i" == "ert7" ]; then
        echo "<html>" > /home/myuser/slavedelay.html
        slvdelay=`mysql  -u$user -p$password -h<ip> -S /backup/mysql/mysql.sock -e 'show slave status\G' | grep Seconds_Behind_Master | sed -e 's/ *Seconds_Behind_Master: //'`
         if [ $slvdelay -ge $threshold ]; then
                echo "<tr><td>$i</td><td>CRITICAL</td>"
        else
                echo "<tr><td>$i</td><td>OK</td>"
         fi | tee -a /home/myuser/slavedelay.html
        echo "</html>" >> /home/myuser/slavedelay.html
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace :

```
if [ "$i" == "ert7" ];
```

with:

```
if [ "$i" = "ert7" ];
```

You use `=` operator in test also.

Comment: I tried, But the same result only. In console it is resulting properly. But not redirecting to the output file(/home/myuser/slavedelay.html)

Comment: It is a logical error, echo "<html>" > /home/myuser/slavedelay.html is given with in the for loop. instead need to give it before the loop.